# Where Fiddler2 stored his temp files

Tags: c#, .net, fiddler

Hello i am trying to get all cookie from url, i am working with watIn and i use this code to get cookie

```
 string cookies = browserToRun.Eval("document.cookie");
 CookieContainer Cc = GetCc(cookies, "www.test.com");
```

this give me 90% of all cookie,but in Fiddler2 i can see more cookie.

Sow if there a way to get to this temp folder where Filddler2 is holding this information?Because i can see it in fiddler2 windows than means it have to be stored some where in my pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddler doesn't store its traffic in *temp files*; you can easily configure Fiddler to export captured traffic anywhere you like.

Having said that, one problem you're having is that the `document.cookie` collection only returns cookies that don't have the `httpOnly` attribute set. The httpOnly attribute is deliberately designed (for security purposes) to omit cookies from the `document.cookie` collection.

Watin likely exposes some other way to get all cookies, including those with the httpOnly attribute.